# Setting up multiple dependent elements (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, data-binding, dependencies

I have a form with dependent dropdowns (cat) which depend on the value selected from an independent dropdown (item). I want to avoid copy paste code so I am looking to have a function that can handle multiple dropdowns based on their independent partner. I dont want to explicitly call the dependent element or I will have to result in copy paste ugly code.

So is there away to bind to elements together, or tie to elements together?

Example:
item1 --> cat1
item2 --> cat2
item3 --> cat3

```
    var roleByCategory = {
        A: ["Soup", "Juice", "Tea", "Others"],
        B: ["Soup", "Juice", "Water", "Others"],
        C: ["Soup", "Juice", "Coffee", "Tea", "Others"]
    }

    $("form").on("change", ".indi_ele", changeCat);
    $(".indi_ele select").change();


    function changeCat(event) { //should handle everything
        var indie = $(event.target);
        var depends = indie.closest('select').find('.gfield_select'); //dependent dropdown
        var type = indie.val(); // this equals A, B, or C

        var catOptions = "";
        for (categoryId = 0; categoryId < roleByCategory[type].length; categoryId++) {
            catOptions += "<option>" + roleByCategory[type][categoryId] + "</option>";
        }
            depends.html(catOptions);
    }
```

Comment: The values I use are not unique to the dropdown. item1 has the same options as item2. BUT item1 needs to only affect cat1 NOT cat2 and item2 needs to only affect cat2 and so on and so forth.

This is the issue I am trying to solve. Trying to get those elements linked so that they only affect elements that they are supposed to affect

Answer (score 0):

Give certain value to the elements of first dropdown and Populate the elements of second dropdown beforehand as well (you may hide it from the user if you want). On change of first dropdown filter the second dropdown using the `filter()` method.

Comment: The values I use are not unique to the dropdown. item1 has the same options as item2. BUT item1 needs to only affect cat1 NOT cat2 and item2 needs to only affect cat2 and so on and so forth.

This is the issue I am trying to solve. Trying to get those elements linked so that they only affect elements that they are supposed to affect